# combination to get ways to group boys and girls

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

if from 5 boys, 3 girls, (n=2, i.e. pair together 2 people), so we need 1 boy & 1 girl. We have 5 ways to choose a boy and 3 ways to choose a girl, so answer is 15.

But if boys is 10, girls are 5 and we need to make a team of 4 people, so we need 2 boys and 2 girls. We can choose 2 boys from a possible 10, and we can choose 2 girls from a possible 5. Then we have 2 different ways to pair the chosen boys and girls. So will the answer be 450 or 900?

Comment: If you  are just choosing a team of two boys and two girls, why are you pairing the boys and girls you have selected?  The problem says nothing about pairing them.

Comment: The answer will be 450 clearly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many ways to assemble a team of 5 out of 15 girls and 10 boys with limitations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73969/how-many-ways-to-assemble-a-team-of-5-out-of-15-girls-and-10-boys-with-limitatio)

Comment: The answer depends on what you need: 450 for a team of four and 900 for two teams of two.